# Need initial N characters of column in Postgres where N is unknown

Tags: string, postgresql, substring

I have one column in my table in Postgres let's say employeeId. We do some modification based on the employee type and store it in DB. Basically, we append strings from these 4 strings `('ACR','AC','DCR','DC')`. Now we can have any combination of these 4 strings appended after employeeId. For example, `EMPIDACRDC`, `EMPIDDCDCRAC` etc. These are valid combinations. I need to retrieve `EMPID` from this. EMPID length is not fixed. The column is of varying length type. How can this be done in Postgres?

Comment: Are you aware that you are violating basic normalization rules with this structure? Never combine different types of information in the same column. Those should be two columns (maybe even a one-to-many relationship to the actual code)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It is a combination of characters(small + capitals) + numbers) + underscore somewhere.

Comment: @scaisEdge, I am not supposed to reveal why and how these 4 strings are chosen as this is my company's project. This will not help to answer the question also. In better way, the question is I have a string EMPID + any combination of the strings ('ACR','AC','DCR','DC'). For ex. EMPID + ACRDCRDC, EMPID + ACDC etc. where emp_id is again combination of (small and capital letters + numbers + underscore). My need is to retrieve EMPID. So basically I want to remove combination of the mentioned 4 strings from the given string column and give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand the question, but `regexp_replace()` seems to do the trick:

```
with sample (employeeid) as (
  values
  ('1ACR'),
  ('2ACRDCR'),
  ('100DCRAC')
)
select employeeid,
       regexp_replace(employeeid, 'ACR|AC|DCR|DC.*$', '', 'gi') as clean_id
from sample
```

returns:

```
employeeid | clean_id
-----------+---------
1ACR       | 1       
2ACRDCR    | 2       
100DCRAC   | 100
```

The regular expression says "any character after any of those string up to the end of the string" - and that is then replace with nothing. This however won't work if the actual empid contains any of those codes that are appended.

---

It would be **much** cleaner to store this information in two columns. One for the empid and one for those "codes"